# Figure out crash reason for a same project which crashes under certain target

Tags: android

I am targeting my application to be able run across Android 1.5 till 2.3. I create 2 AVDs

```
Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10) 
Android 1.5   (API Level 3)
```

I found out my application able to launch in Android 2.3, but not 1.5. It crashes even before the application able to show up. I try to find out the root cause using the following way. Here is what I did.

**I made the build target pointed to Android 1.5**
[image]

**I Debug As -> 1 Android Application**
[image]

The crash breakpoint is pointing to Android code, and not my application code.

**If I just Run As -> 1 Android Application, I will get the following**
[image]

**If I run the same source code, by targeting Android 2.3.3, the application can be launched without problem.**

[image]

What is the correct way, for me to figure out, why the same project can crash under certain target, but run well under another target.

Comment: You may be using some api or class that is available from API level 10 or above.please check the Logcat for the cause of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there are more error specific messages in logcat. 
If that doesn't help I suggest you comment out all non-vital parts of your main Activity to see if the error dissappears. If it does, reintroduce the code parts out you commented out one by one to pinpoint what is causing the error.

BTW, do you really need to be 1.5 compliant? Hardly anyone is using it these days (see [stats here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html))